# Converting from `NSDecimal` or `NSDecimalNumber` to C#'s `decimal` type

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, type-conversion, decimal, nsdecimalnumber

I've got an `NSDecimalNumber` from StoreKit's `SKProduct` class, and I want to convert it to C#'s `decimal` type to minimize loss of precision. Is there a straightforward way to do such a thing?

I figure my two choices are:

1. Assume that I understand the binary implementation of each and do my own bit-wise conversion, or
2. Have `NSDecimalNumber` give me a string and then have `decimal` parse it.

I figure option 1 is way too much work and probably even brittle, so I'm inclined to go with option 2. But that doesn't seem like the best I can do, either. (I can live with how slow it'll be, because it happens exceptionally rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Xamarin iOS SDK 12, operators are available for [explicitly converting an NSDecimal to a decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsdecimal.op_explicit?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#Foundation_NSDecimal_op_Explicit_Foundation_NSDecimal__System_Decimal) and [implicitly converting a decimal to an NSDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsdecimal.op_implicit?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#Foundation_NSDecimal_op_Implicit_System_Decimal__Foundation_NSDecimal).

Using these operators, you can take the following code as an example for achieving your goal:

```
var nsDecimalNumber = new NSDecimalNumber("128.478", new NSLocale("en-US"));
var nsDecimal = nsDecimalNumber.NSDecimalValue;
var csharpDecimal = (decimal)nsDecimal;
var nsDecimalAfterConversion = (NSDecimal)csharpDecimal;
var nsDecimalNumberAfterConversion = new NSDecimalNumber(nsDecimalAfterConversion);
```

Answer (score 5):

[`NSDecimal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDecimal) and [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) structures representation are not identical to .NET [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x.aspx).

Conversion is always possible but not easy. If performance is not a huge matter then you'll best served by using the `string` representation to convert between them.

Comment: Problem is that `decimal.Parse()` is not reliable between different cultures.  If `NSDecimalNumber` produces the string `4.99` and you use `decimal.Parse` on an iPad set to, say, Sweden, you will get a parse error since it's expecting `4,99` instead of `4.99`.  (this is an actual issue for me since `NSDecimalNumber` is *always* returning `4.99` no matter what culture my iPad is set to.)

Comment: Not a problem :-) There's an overload for `Decimal.Parse` that accept a `CultureInfo` -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx quote: The provider parameter is an IFormatProvider implementation, such as a NumberFormatInfo or CultureInfo object.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot for not thinking of that.  Thanks for the tip, worked like a champ!

Comment: Maybe Xamarin should add a better method to convert decimals.

Answer (score 4):

Just because this tripped me up and cost me quite some time here's a couple extension methods I now use for conversion between `NSDecimal` and `decimal`. This was quite frustrating and I am surprised there is no better way built in.

```
public static class NumberHelper
{
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this NSDecimal number)
    {
        var stringRepresentation = new NSDecimalNumber (number).ToString ();
        return decimal.Parse(stringRepresentation, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static NSDecimal ToNSDecimal(this decimal number)
    {
        return new NSDecimalNumber(number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).NSDecimalValue;
    }
}
```