# How do I convert an NSDecimal to an C# decimal

Tags: c#, monomac

I have an NSObject which might be an NSDecimal or NSDecimalNumber. If it is either, I'd like to convert it to a C# decimal value. How can I do this?

```
        if (o is NSDecimalNumber) {
            var dn = (NSDecimalNumber)o;
            return (decimal)(Somehow(dn));              
        }

        if (o is NSDecimal) {
            var d = (NSDecimal)o;
            return (decimal)(Somehow(d));
        }
```

Comment: How are you receiving this `NSObject` instance in your C#? Maybe you could show us some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731721/converting-from-nsdecimal-or-nsdecimalnumber-to-cs-decimal-type

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (o is NSDecimalNumber || o is NSDecimal) {
            return decimal.Parse (o.ToString (), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
```